# Get annotation value of child in constructor

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I am trying to get an annotation of a child class within the constructor of an abstract parent.

```
public abstract class Skill {
private String identifier;

public Skill(){
    identifier = getClass().getAnnotation(SerializableAs.class).value();
}
...
}
```

And the child looks like this:

```
@SerializableAs("TestSkill")
public class TestSkill extends Skill { ... }
```

Obviously the code above returns an NPE, because getAnnotation returns null for Skill, but is there a way to get the annotation from the child?

Because of the way how SerializableAs is involved in other fundamental parts of the system and how I create a new instance of TestSkill (via dynamic jar loading/reflection), I would like to avoid to have a parameter in the constructor. I also want to verify that the SerializableAs is exactly the same as the identifier.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is a link to the SerializeAs annotation I work with:
https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/serialization/SerializableAs.java

EDIT: Found it, I am stupid, it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it obviously throw an NPE? `getClass()` should return `TestSkill.class` according to runtime polymorphism...

Comment: getClass() returns the subclass, which is annotated. So the absence of annotation on the base class is not the problem. See the answer of Sotirios.

Comment: hmm. that's weird, I got an NPE in the getClass line and this seemed to be the only explanation. I double checked that the imports are correct and there is definitely the value set for the TestSkill class

Comment: fixed it. One line beneath, I feel dumb. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to annotate your annotation with

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

This will make it available (through reflection) at run time.

> I also want to verify that the `SerializableAs` is exactly the same as
>   the identifier.

You'll have to validate the value returned by `value()` yourself at run time.

---

Note that nothing in your code is forcing an implementation of `Skill` to have an annotation. Someone could make a sub type that doesn't have it. You should take that into account and maybe move your logic to somewhere else or change the logic to also do a `null` check.

Comment: Thanks, I verify the existence of the annotation while loading the class. As mentioned in the comments above, I double checked everything and the RetetionType is also set to runtime. I will add a link to the interface source

Comment: Fixed it. The NPE is one line below... :P Thanks. I will mark this as the solution, because it would have been the RetentionPolicy overwise.